# Connection Timeout Error in JMeter Distributed Enviroment

Tags: jmeter, rmi, jmeter-5.0

### Command use to run in Master machine

```
mvn clean verify -DjMeterTestFile=Script_Name.jmx -Dremote_hosts='slave machine IP"
```

In Master machine test is getting executed and no errors getting logged

### Slave Machine Command

```
sh /'jmeter file path'/jmeter-server -Djava.rmi.server.hostname='Slave machine IP'
```

### I'm Getting the below error in Jmeter Slave log once after the Test started

```
2019-02-14 06:42:45,001 ERROR o.a.j.s.RemoteListenerWrapper: testStarted(host) on 'Slave Machine IP'
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 'Server machine IP'; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:129) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.testStarted(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteListenerWrapper.testStarted(RemoteListenerWrapper.java:79) [ApacheJMeter_core-5.0.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:217) [ApacheJMeter_core-5.0.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:384) [ApacheJMeter_core-5.0.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_191]
```

### Configurations setup in Master Machine and Slave Agent

### Master Machine Configurations

```
client.rmi.localport : 5060
https.socket.protocols: TLS1.2v
java.rmi.server.hostname : slave machine IP
server.rmi.ssl.disable : true

Plugins and Versions used
com.lazerycode.jmeter version 2.8.0
kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-extras:1.4.0
kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-standard:1.4.0
kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-autostop:0.1
kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-casutg:2.6
kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-csvars:0.1
kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-functions:2.0
kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-manager:0.19
kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-perfmon:2.1
kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-prmctl:0.3
kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-tst:2.1
kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-webdriver:2.3
com.blazemeter:jmeter-parallel:0.7
com.blazemeter:jmeter-plugins-wsc:0.7
```

### Slave Machine Configurations

```
java.rmi.server.hostname='Slave Machine IP'
server.rmi.localport=42840
https.socket.protocols=TLSv1.2
server.rmi.ssl.disable=true
```

For the same configurations I'm not getting errors in JMeter 4.0

Comment: Looks like you need to use `java.rmi.server.hostname' at the master as well.

Comment: I have done it already not working

Answer (score 0):

It was observed that results were sent through port 5061 and 5062. Therefore Had to open ports 5061 and 5062 in Controller machine .

`Ex : sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 10.0.0.0/0 --dport 5061 -j ACCEPT`

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue with Jmeter on a windows client and flushing the DNS cache seems to fix my environment.

- open Powershell from the windows start menu
- type and run "Clear-DnsClientCache"
- try again. Restarting Jmeter doesn't seem necessary.